# App crashing on start, i review the code but did't get anything

Tags: android

## SliderScreen Code

```
package com.example.coder.thecompleteeduhub;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager slideViewpage;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private SliderAdapter sliderAdapter;
    private TextView[] dots;
    private Button btnBack,btnNext;
    private int mCurrentPage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        slideViewpage=findViewById(R.id.sliderViewPager);
        linearLayout=findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        sliderAdapter =new SliderAdapter(this);
        btnBack=findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        btnNext=findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        slideViewpage.setAdapter(sliderAdapter);
        addDotIndicator(0);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                slideViewpage.setCurrentItem(mCurrentPage+1);
            }
        });
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                slideViewpage.setCurrentItem(mCurrentPage-1);
            }
        });
    }
    public void addDotIndicator(int position)
    {
        dots=new TextView[5];
        linearLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i=0; i<=dots.length;i++)
        {
            dots[i]=new TextView(this);
            dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            dots[i].setTextSize(35);
            dots[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTransparentWhite));
            linearLayout.addView(dots[i]);
            slideViewpage.addOnPageChangeListener(viewListner);
        }
        if (dots.length>0)
        {
            dots[position].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
        }
    }
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewListner=new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            addDotIndicator(i);
            mCurrentPage = i;
            if (i==0)
            {
                btnNext.setEnabled(true);
                btnBack.setEnabled(false);
                btnBack.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btnNext.setText("Next");
                btnBack.setText("");
            }
            else if (i==dots.length-1)
            {
                btnNext.setEnabled(true);
                btnBack.setEnabled(true);
                btnBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnNext.setText("Finish");
                btnBack.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                btnNext.setEnabled(true);
                btnBack.setEnabled(true);
                btnBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnNext.setText("Next");
                btnBack.setText("Back");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    };
}
```

## Slider Adapter Class

```
package com.example.coder.thecompleteeduhub;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager slideViewpage;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private SliderAdapter sliderAdapter;
    private TextView[] dots;
    private Button btnBack,btnNext;
    private int mCurrentPage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        slideViewpage=findViewById(R.id.sliderViewPager);
        linearLayout=findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        sliderAdapter =new SliderAdapter(this);
        btnBack=findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        btnNext=findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        slideViewpage.setAdapter(sliderAdapter);
        addDotIndicator(0);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                slideViewpage.setCurrentItem(mCurrentPage+1);
            }
        });
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                slideViewpage.setCurrentItem(mCurrentPage-1);
            }
        });
    }
    public void addDotIndicator(int position)
    {
        dots=new TextView[5];
        linearLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i=0; i<=dots.length;i++)
        {
            dots[i]=new TextView(this);
            dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            dots[i].setTextSize(35);
            dots[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTransparentWhite));
            linearLayout.addView(dots[i]);
            slideViewpage.addOnPageChangeListener(viewListner);
        }
        if (dots.length>0)
        {
            dots[position].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
        }
    }
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewListner=new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            addDotIndicator(i);
            mCurrentPage = i;
            if (i==0)
            {
                btnNext.setEnabled(true);
                btnBack.setEnabled(false);
                btnBack.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btnNext.setText("Next");
                btnBack.setText("");
            }
            else if (i==dots.length-1)
            {
                btnNext.setEnabled(true);
                btnBack.setEnabled(true);
                btnBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnNext.setText("Finish");
                btnBack.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                btnNext.setEnabled(true);
                btnBack.setEnabled(true);
                btnBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnNext.setText("Next");
                btnBack.setText("Back");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    };
}
```

## Slider Screen XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/sliderViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="164dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="164dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_previous" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

## SlideLayout Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSlide"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icons8_university_64" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slider_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="226dp"
        android:text="@string/university_slider"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slider_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="363dp"
        android:text="@string/university_slider_detail"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

## Logcat error :

```
Process: com.example.coder.thecompleteeduhub, PID: 24169
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.coder.thecompleteeduhub/com.example.coder.thecompleteeduhub.SplashScreen}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
        at com.example.coder.thecompleteeduhub.SplashScreen.addDotIndicator(SplashScreen.java:51)
        at com.example.coder.thecompleteeduhub.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
10-09 16:29:14.161 2640-24365/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
10-09 16:29:14.161 2640-24365/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
10-09 16:29:14.161 2640-24365/? E/android.os.Debug: sys.mobilecare.preload = false
10-09 16:29:14.851 24395-24395/? E/Zygote: v2
```

Image for SliderScreen(MainScreen)
[SliderScreen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrd2W.png)
[SliderLayout Layout Design Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26h78.png)

I see many times but still not getting solution. Please help to get find out the error.
I seen a ArrayBoundException error but i seen that as well but no t fixed

Comment: The problem is here in **`addDotIndicator()`** method use this `for (int i=0; i<dots.length;i++)` instead of  `for (int i=0; i<=dots.length;i++)`

Comment: Use `for (int i=0; i<dots.length;i++)` in `addDotIndicator` method

Answer (score 1):

Use this `for (int i=0; i<dots.length;i++)` instead of `for (int i=0; i<=dots.length;i++)`